# Stop login with phone number if it is not linked in firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am integrating Firebase authentication in my mobile applications with email and phone number login enabled. Login with email/phone and phone number linking is working as expected. Current flow:

signup with email -> link phone number -> dashboard.

When I login with email, I can check if the email already exists or not. Is it possible with phone number? So that user complete signup flow first.

Comment: With your signup flow, phone number won't be added unless user registers on your app. If your authentication doesn't contain phone number, it'll just say phone number not found, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API that allows you to look up providers by phone number (similar to [`findSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html). It actually sounds like a useful addition, so I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

But there **is** a server-side method to find the UID by phone number: [`getUserByPhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUserByPhoneNumber). You could wrap this in Cloud Functions, or another endpoint on whatever server-side you prefer, and call that from your application.